# My android application is getting stopped

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview

My android application is getting stopped it is a runtime error:

> inflating class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout

Log cat:

```
    Process: coml.example.pandey.firebasedatabase, PID: 31613
                                                                                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{coml.example.pandey.firebasedatabase/coml.example.pandey.firebasedatabase.LoginActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.
                                                                                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:207)
                                                                                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatActivity.java:130)
                                                                                      at coml.example.pandey.firebasedatabase.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:36)
                                                                                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
                                                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

My LoginActivity.java oncreate code is

```
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

My activity_login:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="coml.xxxxxx.firebasedatabase.LoginActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="@dimen/logo_w_h"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/logo_w_h"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:hint="@string/hint_email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textColorHint="@android:color/white" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/password"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:hint="@string/hint_password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textColorHint="@android:color/white" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <!-- Login Button -->

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_login"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:text="@string/btn_login"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_reset_password"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
        android:background="@null"
        android:text="@string/btn_forgot_password"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent" />

    <!-- Link to Login Screen -->

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_signup"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
        android:background="@null"
        android:text="@string/btn_link_to_register"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="15dp" />
</LinearLayout>

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:visibility="gone" />
 </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: show XML please. Make sure Your `LoginActivity` extends `AppCompatActivity `

Comment: add your layout.xml file with question

Comment: i have posted xml file please check

Comment: @varunpandey remove unwanted space from header.

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya removed header unwanted spaces but still same crash

Comment: have you added design dependency in gradle file

Comment: For future questions please post the full logcat, usually there is useful information later in the stack trace (watch out for lines starting "caused by")

Comment: A new logcat  error found

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{coml.example.pandey.firebasedatabase/coml.example.pandey.firebasedatabase.LoginActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.

Comment: @Henry i have posted the whole logcat can you please help Me

Comment: What is not clear in `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.`?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: That's odd Varun, I'm sure I asked you to desist from urgent begging [on your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45095295). And here you are at it again, this time vandalising the title with pleading messages. It looks like you intend to ignore the community wishes on this, but you'll hit the question ban soon, and will not be able to ask any more questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the your Manifest file and do this in the activity where you want to show the Toolbar

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity"  
 android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"><!-- ADD THIS LINE -->
```

Then in styles.xml add the following:

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

update your activity_login.xml file

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="coml.xxxxxx.firebasedatabase.LoginActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />



    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="@dimen/logo_w_h"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/logo_w_h"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:hint="@string/hint_email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textColorHint="@android:color/white" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/password"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:hint="@string/hint_password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textColorHint="@android:color/white" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <!-- Login Button -->

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_login"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:text="@string/btn_login"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_reset_password"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
        android:background="@null"
        android:text="@string/btn_forgot_password"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent" />

    <!-- Link to Login Screen -->

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_signup"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
        android:background="@null"
        android:text="@string/btn_link_to_register"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="15dp" />
</LinearLayout>

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:visibility="gone" />
 </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: yes i have updated app level build.gradle file but still the error is same

Comment: a new locat error   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{coml.example.pandey.firebasedatabase/coml.example.pandey.firebasedatabase.LoginActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.

Comment: Thank you soo much for your support my problem is solved